# $\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ has no primitive in $\{|z| >1 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to show that: $\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ has no primitive function in $\{|z| >1 \}$, well it seems to me that the way to do it is to find a close simple curve $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \{|z|>1\}$ such that the line integral $\int_{z\in \gamma}\frac{z}{z^2+1} \neq 0$.

I tried the circle $\partial B(0,2)$ and a ball of radius $\varepsilon>0$ around $2i$ , i.e $2i+\varepsilon e^{i\theta} , \theta\in[0,2\pi]$, When the latter approach was chosen due to the splitting $\frac{z}{z^2+1} = \frac{i}{2}[\frac{z}{z+i} -\frac{z}{z-i}]$.

Yet I couldn't solve the integrals.

Other directions or ideas for how to choose the curve $\gamma$ , or how to solve the integrals for $\gamma$-s above would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your partial fraction decomposition is wrong. We have that

$$\begin{align}\frac z{z^2+1}=\frac A{z+i}+\frac B{z-i}&\iff A(z-i)+B(z+i)=z\\&\iff A+B=1\land B-A=0\\&\iff A=B=\frac12\end{align}$$ so

$$2\oint\frac{z}{z^2+1}dz=\oint\frac1{z-i}dz+\oint\frac1{z+i}dz=4\pi i$$

for a contour around zero of radius greater than one.

Comment: In what this show that $\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ has no primitive ?

Comment: @user657324 if an integral over a closed path is non zero then we can't define properly a primitive in all the space, that is, we don't have a function $F\in C^1(\Bbb C\setminus\{-i,i\})$ such that $F'(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+1}$